# What terminal defaults command will show menu bar icons in macOS?

Tags: terminal, menu-bar, defaults

In Catalina, allowed ZSH full disk access in preferences and ran

```
defaults write com.apple.systemuiserver menuExtras -array 
    "/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Bluetooth.menu"
    "/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Clock.menu" 
    "/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Displays.menu"
    "/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Volume.menu"
    killall SystemUIServer
```

Its not refreshing the menu bar to show bluetooth, volume, battery and airplay icons. Is there a change or different command that makes it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can no longer hide the clock; it is an always-visible UI element that controls Notification Center.

For the rest, you can use the command

```
defaults write \
    ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.controlcenter.plist \
    "$SERVICE" \
    -int "$MAGIC_NUMBER"
```

`$SERVICE` can be one of:

- `Bluetooth`
- `Display` (for what used to be `Displays`)
- `Sound` (for what used to be `Volume`)

and `$MAGIC_NUMBER` can be `18` for "visible in menu bar", or `24` for "not visible in menu bar".

Comment: I wonder if https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/462062/how-can-i-make-macos-always-show-the-bluetooth-icon-in-the-top-bar-even-when-it would also be answered by your answer. I'm guessing not.

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly